# How can I pickle the best model from a grid search?

Tags: scikit-learn

After I perform grid search CV, I would like to pickle the best model to use in the future.  When I do something like

```
grid_search = GridSearchCV(SVC_clf, parameters, n_jobs=-1, verbose=1, cv = 3)

gs = grid_search.fit(X, Y)


with open('../MLA (pickled)/SVC.txt','w') as f:
    s = pickle.dumps(gs)
    f.write(s)
```

and then

```
with open('../MLA (pickled)/SVC.txt','r') as f:
    clf = pickle.loads( f.read() )
clf.fit(X_new,Y_new)
```

the grid search is started once more.  This would be extremely painful, especially if the parameter grid was very large.

How can I pickle the "best" model from grid search?

Answer (score 2):

Oh, I see.  It seems `gs` as a `best_estimator_`.  So I should pickle `gs.best_estimator_`.